# How to make (:hover:before) pseudo elements remain in effect while drop-down menu is open?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, pseudo-class

I'm facing some specific challenges on my current project: I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I got a couple of menu buttons, by hovering which a multi-level drop-down menu should appear. According to design, a tiny triangle (pointer arrow) should also appear underneath the button (on hover). So, for this purpose I've used [Ian Lunn's](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) hover effects by slightly tweaking the desired effect as per my own needs. Here's the markup:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><button class="btn nav_lower_button">Participants</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn nav_lower_button">Activities</button></li>
    <li id="order" class="dropdown"><button id="place_order" class="btn nav_lower_button dropdown-toggle bubble-bottom" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Partners</button>
         <ul id="order_drop" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

And the CSS part:

```
.nav_lower_button {
background-color: transparent;
color: #fafafa;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.286em
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
border-color: transparent;
outline: none;
}

.nav_lower_button:hover, .nav_lower_button:focus {
background-color: #ed1d48;
color: #ffffff;
}

/* Bubble Bottom */
.bubble-bottom {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.bubble-bottom:before {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
content: '';
border-style: solid;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
transition-duration: 0.1s;
-webkit-transition-property: bottom;
transition-property: bottom;
left: calc(20% - 10px);
bottom: 0;
border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent transparent;
}
.bubble-bottom:hover:before, .bubble-bottom:focus:before, .bubble-bottom:active:before .bubble-     bottom.bubbled_down {
bottom: -10px;
border-color: #ed1d48 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

I wonder how I could keep this pointer arrow remain while the drop-down is active. I need it to appear on hover (which it actually does), but I want it to remain when a drop-down menu is open (but when I leave the mouse from the button itself). I've tried several options in jQuery - everything works fine except the fact that I cannot have this 'arrow' remain. The button's on-hover background remains, but the arrow goes back. 
Any alternative approach or idea is welcome,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbpupnqj/3/)

```
.nav_lower_button {
background-color: transparent;
color: #fafafa;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.286em
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
border-color: transparent;
outline: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .nav_lower_button,.nav_lower_button:hover, .nav_lower_button:focus {
background-color: #ed1d48;
color: #ffffff;
}

/* Bubble Bottom */
.bubble-bottom {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.bubble-bottom:before {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
content: '';
border-style: solid;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
transition-duration: 0.1s;
-webkit-transition-property: bottom;
transition-property: bottom;
left: calc(20% - 10px);
bottom: 0;
border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent transparent;
}
.dropdown:hover .bubble-bottom:before ,.bubble-bottom:hover:before, .bubble-bottom:focus:before, .bubble-bottom:active:before .bubble-     bottom.bubbled_down {
bottom: -10px;
border-color: #ed1d48 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```